# Check if user input into a ASP.net webform Textbox exists in a SQL column

Tags: sql, asp.net, validation, webforms

How can I validate the user input to a data in a SQL table?

I want to ensure the users can only input Part Numbers that are in a SQL table.

It is a Web form in ASP.net.

```
    private static List<string> AutoFillProducts(string prefixText)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand())
            {
                com.CommandText = "select PART from PARTSTABLE where " + "LOWER (PART) like @Search + '%'";

                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", prefixText);
                com.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                List<string> parts = new List<string>();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        parts.Add(sdr["PART"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
                return parts;


            }

        }
    }


    <asp:TextBox ID="txtpart" runat="server" Height="30px" input type="text" placeholder="Enter Part" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onblur="onLeave(this)" OnTextChanged="txtpart_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" MinimumPrefixLength="4"
                CompletionInterval="5" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="1" TargetControlID="txtpart" 
                ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected="false">
            </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, please post what you have tried, related code, any errors you might have received.

Comment: @AdamBushell If the list of `sql` values is not too large, you could just load those values into a `select` or `ul` for selection by the user instead of trying to validate their text input. In other words, don't use a `textbox` at all.

Comment: @mxmissile I forgot to add the code that gives me the auto suggestion based on first 4 characters. How can i validate the user input into the text box  based on the SQL column to prevent any parts being added that don't exist.

Comment: @RyanWilson the list is huge unfortunately :(

Comment: @AdamBushell This link is an implementation of the autocomplete textbox. The thing that you might wanna have. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3_5gnTIS4E